# How do I get depth_image_proc?

Tags: ros, macos, macos-lion, osx, depth-image-proc

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The package summary for [depth_image_proc](http://www.ros.org/wiki/depth_image_proc) say it is **new in ROS Electric** however my Electric (OSX 10.7.3) doesn't have it installed under the image_pipeline folder. I tried updating my ROS Electric using "rosinstall ." but nothing got downloaded/updated that gave me depth_image_proc. Is there a proper way to update my Electric install to get this or is it really an experimental package that I must manually install using SVN?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/31520/how-do-i-get-depth_image_proc?/) by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2962 on 2012-04-09

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2012-04-09**:
It isn't present on my Ubuntu 11.10 Electric install either. It is present in image_pipeline in my Fuerte install from .debs. Perhaps that should be "new in Fuerte"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`depth_image_proc` was indeed introduced in ROS Electric, but in the `openni_kinect` stack. In Fuerte I've moved it to `image_pipeline` as it should be useful for working with 3D cameras in general, not only the Kinect.

I'll make a note in the wiki docs.

---

Originally posted by [Patrick Mihelich](https://answers.ros.org/users/180/patrick-mihelich/) with karma: 4336 on 2012-04-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) on 2012-04-10**:
Thanks!!!!